# Outlook CSS Rendering Different From Browser

Tags: html, css, outlook, office365

I have some html that I am modifying, and everything is rendering in my browser as intended. I left the logo out of this example.

[image]

The same code is rendering as follows in an email:
[image]
Notice how the first div doesn't wrap around the second as it does in the browser. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

    <head>
        <title>
            Message
        </title>
        <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css">
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: #4da9ff;
            }
            a{
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: #4da9ff;
            }

            .ReadMsgBody {
            width: 100%;
            }

            .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
            }

            .ExternalClass * {
            line-height: 100%;
            }

            body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            }

            table,
            td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
            }

            img {
            border: 0;
            height: auto;
            line-height: 100%;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            }

            p {
            display: block;
            margin: 13px 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <style type="text/css">
            @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
            @-ms-viewport {
            width: 320px;
            }
            @viewport {
            width: 320px;
            }
            }
        </style>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso]>
            <xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte mso 11]>
            <style type="text/css">
            .outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
            </style>
        <![endif]-->


        <style type="text/css">
            @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
            .mj-column-per-100 {
            width: 100% !important;
            }
            }
        </style>


        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            }

            td {
            padding: 0;
            }

            p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head> 
<body>
<div style="background-color: #f9f9fb;width: 100%; height: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Geneva, Century Gothic, Arial, sans-serif;">
<table style="background-color: #0695e4; width: 100%; height: 80px; vertical-align: middle;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 70%;">
<h2 style="margin: 0 10px; color: white">Message From a Friend</h2>
</td>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;"><img style="margin: 0 10px; width: auto; max-height:100%;" src="empty" alt="Logo" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Please take action below</h3>
<div style="margin: 20px; background-color: white; padding: 20px;">
<p style="word-break: break-all;">Dear friend,</p>
<br />
<p style="word-break: break-all;"><a href="somelink">Click here</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: EMail CSS is a very different beast and can be quite complicated at times. Imagine ~1996 CSS. There are special tools and CSS frameworks to normalize and deal with this but in general you shouldn't expect "regular" css to properly work in emails.

Comment: Yes, and this is why tables are still used for email layout even though the practice has all but disappeared from the modern web.

Comment: You might try `overflow: hidden` on the offending element.

Comment: @isherwood I gave that a shot, no luck. And yeah I'm aware it's quite a different beast. To be honest I'm not sure where to start regarding converting this to tables. Most of the code was provided to me.

Answer (score 0):

As stated and as you are aware, the code bases for front end and email are different.
I would start with converting the div to tables. People do use them but without the knowledge of their quirks, it's best to fall back to basic table structure as it is the most bulletproof HTML email coding technique.

Here are a few amendments to your code:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

    <head>
        <title>
            Message
        </title>
        <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css">
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: #4da9ff;
            }
            a{
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: #4da9ff;
            }

            .ReadMsgBody {
            width: 100%;
            }

            .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
            }

            .ExternalClass * {
            line-height: 100%;
            }

            body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            }

            table,
            td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
            }

            img {
            border: 0;
            height: auto;
            line-height: 100%;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            }

            p {
            display: block;
            margin: 13px 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <style type="text/css">
            @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
            @-ms-viewport {
            width: 320px;
            }
            @viewport {
            width: 320px;
            }
            }
        </style>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso]>
            <xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte mso 11]>
            <style type="text/css">
            .outlook-group-fix { width:100% !important; }
            </style>
        <![endif]-->


        <style type="text/css">
            @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
            .mj-column-per-100 {
            width: 100% !important;
            }
            }
        </style>


        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            }

            td {
            padding: 0;
            }

            p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head> 
<body style="background-color:#f9f9fb">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Geneva, Century Gothic, Arial, sans-serif;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #0695e4; height:80px;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 70%;">
                                            <h2 style="margin: 0 10px; color: white">Message From a Friend</h2>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 30%; text-align: center;"><img style="margin: 0 10px; width: auto; max-height:100%;" src="empty" alt="Logo" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Please take action below</h3>
                
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="margin: 20px; background-color:#ffffff; padding: 20px;">
                                <p style="word-break: break-all;">Dear friend,</p>
                                <br />
                                <p style="word-break: break-all;"><a href="somelink">Click here</a></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Notes:

1. Avoid using background colours on tables. I've also seen this used by other email devs but personally that goes against the standardized rules of table structure. Table cells () are the tags to add background colours, images and padding, as I have done in my code.
2. To get the grey background on the entire body of the email, add this colour declaration to the body tag.

Let us know how this works!